# Have chrome ask to download location start at most recently saved location

Tags: google-chrome

I like choosing where chrome saves a new download but would like to have the initial location to default to where the most recent save location was in order to cut down on renavigation to that directory. Anyone know a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you can change chrome's initial download directories. What I do know is is that if you use an Internet Download Manager (IDM), it would be added as an extension to your browser. Now, every time you click a download link, the download manager window will show and you can choose from there where to place the downloaded file. It will, by default, add some folders to your downloads folder as a way to organize downloaded files by type (music, video, programs, documents, and compressed) which I really like. It does not require, however, for you to save these types in their specified folders as you have the option for it to "remember" a location for each individual type, which I believe is what you are wanting.
IDM is far more than just that, it also makes downloads faster by making sure your connection never goes idle ensuring that you have the fastest connection possible that your internet plan will allow. 
If you want to use it, you can download it here:   http://mirror2.internetdownloadmanager.com/idman625build21.exe?v=lt&filename=idman625build21.exe

Comment: Thanks. I'll look into some download manager extensions and see which might have the features i'm looking for.